# SQL find out joined table has no record in recent 30 days

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I would like to query out the active **store** which doesn't have any new **product** in recent 30 days in `SQL Server`.

Here is the schema of the tables

Table `Store`

```
int    | id       | 
string | status   |
```

Table `Product`

```
int      | id       | 
string   | name     |
datetime | created_at |
int      | store_id |
```

At first, I wrote something like this

```
select s.*
from Store as s
join Product p on s.id = p.store_id
where s.status = 'active'
and p.created_at < DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE())
```

Apparently, this isn't right and will query out all stores as long as they have a product created before 30 days.

Comment: So you need to find the max created_at value for each store and then test it against the target date. Different ways to do that - and be sure you have a store with NO products in your sample test data.

Comment: @SMor yup, the max created_at may work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you can use `NOT EXISTS` like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM Store s
WHERE s.Status = 'Active'
AND NOT EXISTS(
               SELECT 1
               FROM Product p
               WHERE p.Store_Id = s.Id
               AND p.Created_At >= DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE())
                )
```

Comment: Hm, I see, another way to think. What does `SELECT 1` mean?

Comment: For purposes of `NOT EXISTS` it's just a placeholder. You could also use `SELECT *` and it would work the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for

```
select  *
from    Store
where   status = 'active'
and id NOT IN (select store_id
from    Product where created_at >= DATEADD(day, -30, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: yup, this one works as well, thanks. is there any difference between them?

Comment: Basically is the way on how you are thinking. On the first answer, you are validating every id  from store in product. The second answer returns all of the store_id from product in the selected range and then store discriminates all of those values.